# Enhanced for loop 2d array in android java class

Tags: java, android

**Hi guys, i am trying to learn how to build apps and small games in android. Can someone explain how the enhanced for loop works in this case and how the if statement in the enhanced for loop checks for the winner? The code is from a tic tac toe game with red and yelow circle. Sorry if the question was already asked. **

```
// 0= yellow player; 1 = red player;

int activePlayer=0;

boolean gameIsActive = true;

//2 means unplayed
int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};

int[][] winningPositions= {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7},{2,6,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};

public void dropIn(View view) {
    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

    int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

    if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameIsActive) {

        gameState[tappedCounter]=activePlayer;

        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

        if (activePlayer == 0) {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            activePlayer = 1;
        } else {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            activePlayer = 0;
        }
        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300);

     for (int[] winningPositon : winningPositions){
         if (gameState[winningPositon[0]]== gameState[winningPositon[1]]&& gameState[winningPositon[1]]==gameState[winningPositon[2]]
                 && gameState[winningPositon[0]]!=2){

        //someone has won
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced loops are nothing but a simpler for of regular for loop .
Below for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```

Can be converted in to enhanced for loop as

```
for (int myValue : myArray) {
    System.out.println(myValue);
}
```

In your case

```
for (int[] winningPositon : winningPositions){
         if (gameState[winningPositon[0]]== gameState[winningPositon[1]]&& gameState[winningPositon[1]]==gameState[winningPositon[2]]
                 && gameState[winningPositon[0]]!=2){
```

"winningPositon" is a 2D array so if iterate over its element you will get a single dimensional array ("winningPosition") on each iteration , rest is the game logic.

Ankit